# Updating an array inside a call back

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have the following two functions:

```
var abc;

function updateNum() {
    abc=0;
    g.dbm.transaction("leagues").objectStore("leagues").openCursor(null, "prev").onsuccess = function (event) {
        var teams, i;

        team.filter({
            attrs: ["tid", "abbrev", "region", "name", "cid"],
            seasonAttrs: ["winp", "playoffRoundsWon"],
            season: g.season
        }, function (teams) {
            // Sort teams by playoffs and winp, for first round
            teams.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.playoffRoundsWon < b.playoffRoundsWon) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.playoffRoundsWon > b.playoffRoundsWon) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return a.winp - b.winp;
            });
            abc+=1;
        });
    };
}

function getNum() {
  return abc;
}
```

What I am trying to do is update the variable abc inside the callback function and then return it. I do this by first calling the `updateNum()` function in another file. Then I assign a variable to the value of `getNum()`

Here is how a sample code would look like:

```
myFile.updateNum();
var number = myFile.getNum();
```

I am currently unable to return the updated value of `num`. `number` keeps returning 0 (the default value) instead of the newly updated value (which is 1).

How can I get it to show an updated value? Please let me know if I need to add any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `updateNum` is async, it would have to take a callback as argument so that you can be notified when the number was updated.

E.g.

```
var num = 0;

function updateNumAsync(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        num = 1;
        callback && callback(num); //call the callback if provided 
    }, 500);
}

updateNumAsync(function (num) {
    console.log(num); //updated num
});
```

Comment: So I added `cb` in the parameters of `updateNum` function. Next, I added `cb && cb(abc)` under the `abc+=1` line. I altered the the `getNum` function to as follows: `getBottomTeams(function(abc){return abc;});` Now, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: getNum is not defined` when I open the console. Am I making some obvious mistake here?

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCouldn'tTalkToTheGirl From what you explained, it seems fine. Perhaps you could repost the relevant part of your modified code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general pattern for using an asynchronous function with a callback to pass the asynchronous results around. What is `team.filter`? You will need to design your code such that the asynchronous portion calls a `callback()` function that was passed to the enclosing function.

If filtering gives you problems you may want to look at https://github.com/caolan/async#filterarr-iterator-callback

```
(function main(){
  getNum(function(err, abc){ 
    console.log('thx for playing '+abc)
  });
})();

function getNum(anotherCallback) {
  // Whatever code relies on the result of an asynchronous function must be
  // placed inside the callback function
  countTeams(function(abc){
    console.log('countTeams completed, abc='+abc);
    var err = null;
    anotherCallback(err, abc);
  });
};

function countTeams(callback){
  var abc=0;
  g.dbm.transaction("leagues").objectStore("leagues").openCursor(null, "prev").onsuccess = function (event) {
    var teams, i;
    // I don't know what this filter function does, I am assuming it's synchronous
    team.filter({
      attrs: ["tid", "abbrev", "region", "name", "cid"],
      seasonAttrs: ["winp", "playoffRoundsWon"],
      season: g.season
    }, function (teams) {
      // Sort teams by playoffs and winp, for first round
      teams.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.playoffRoundsWon < b.playoffRoundsWon) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.playoffRoundsWon > b.playoffRoundsWon) {
          return 1;
        }
        return a.winp - b.winp;
      });
      abc+=1;
    });
    return callback(abc); // 0 or n depending on what team.filter does
  };
};
```